# Why is Python not recognizing the elements in a set?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove elements from a set of strings, but they are not being found.
The set is generated as a frozenset (by a library that is out of the scope of the question) which I convert to a regular set.

```
>>> geneset = model.reactions[2915].genes
>>> geneset
frozenset(['YGL080W', 'YGR243W', 'YHR162W', 'AND', 'OR'])
>>> geneset_mutable = set(geneset)
>>> geneset_mutable
set(['YGR243W', 'OR', 'YGL080W', 'AND', 'YHR162W'])
>>> 'OR' in geneset_mutable
False
>>> "OR" in geneset_mutable
False
>>> geneset_mutable.remove('OR')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'OR'
```

The set is editable:

```
>>> geneset_mutable.add('OR')
>>> "OR" in geneset_mutable
True
>>> geneset_mutable.remove('OR')
>>> "OR" in geneset_mutable
False
>>> geneset_mutable
set(['YGR243W', 'AND', 'YHR162W', 'OR', 'YGL080W'])
>>> geneset_mutable.remove('OR')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'OR'
```

Why is the element not being found?
Is there any particular way I can debug this?

For the record:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

Comment: Your questionable set only contains a list, you search for a string ("OR"). It is true that the list in the set contains your string, but the string is not an element of the set.

Comment: @Sirac - Not so.  That's how python displays a set in the interactive terminal.  A list can't be a member of a set because a list isn't hashable.

Comment: Can you show us what `[repr(g) for g in geneset]` comes back with?  Maybe you're seeing an object that's not actually `"OR"`.

Comment: While you're at it: `[type(g) for g in geneset]`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I'm sorry, I am using python3 and didnt know how sets are displayed prior to python3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to type in the set directly, it works fine:

```
geneset_mutable = set(['YGR243W', 'OR', 'YGL080W', 'AND', 'YHR162W'])
>>> "OR" in geneset_mutable
True
```

I conclude that `model.reactions[2915].genes` is not returning strings, it returns genes whose *repr* looks like "OR" but is a different type of object (one that doesn't match your query).

This is easy to confirm, just run a test like this:

```
for gene in geneset:
    if repr(gene) == 'OR':
       print repr(gene)
       print type(gene)
       print gene == 'OR'
```

The solution will be to create a *gene* object that can exactly match the member of the set.  How you do this depends on how your models are implemented but it should look something like this:

```
>>> geneset = model.reactions[2915].genes
>>> Gene('OR') in geneset
True
```

Hope this puts you back on the path to getting you genetic analysis done :-)

Comment: Indeed, instead of `Gene('OR') in geneset` which might cause trouble, I'd do `stringset = set(repr(gene) for gene in geneset)` and then do my `in` operations with `stringset`. Or, if possible, modify the `Gene` object to make it compare with the representing strings.

Comment: Indeed, the repr is hidinh a Gene object, not a simple string. I din't know how to find out if that was the case, but the `print type(gene)` part solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When I copy your commands ad-verbatim, then `'OR' in geneset_mutable` returns `True`. I wonder if there is some non-printable characters trailing the elements in your set. Try the following:

```
new_set = set(map(lambda x: x.strip(), set(geneset)))
```

Does `'OR' in new_set` evaluate to `True` now?

If that doesn't work, I would also try `set(geneset).add('OR')`. You will most likely see `'OR'` twice in the set indicating that it is not the 'OR' you think it is.

Lastly, because Python is strongly typed, you can try printing the type of each element in geneset.

```
for i in geneset:
  print type(i)
```